# Java Extracting Data from Excel sheet

Tags: java, excel, apache-poi

I'm using Apache POI to extract rows from a spreadsheet. That part is simple enough, however, I have a question about this next part.

Let's say I have a table with 2 rows:

```
Name   |   ID    |    Location    |     Date
Joe    |   27    |       UK       |     Sept 21
```

After I extract the data from the table, and put it into its own ArrayList,
I have a list columnValues that I have to reference (just an example)

```
ArrayList<String> NAMES = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList("Name", "First Name"));
ArrayList<String> IDs = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList("ID", "ID #"));
ArrayList<ArrayList<String>> COLUMNVALUES = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList(NAMES, IDs));
```

I can extract the data from the rows just fine, but which data type would be best if I want to check if the items in the first row of the table are in the columnValues list? It's getting confusing with ArrayLists.

Basically I have to check if the top row (Name, ID, Location, Date) are in the list columnvalues, and was trying to find a better data type to do this with. Thanks for the help!

Comment: have you tried something like this:
`For (int i = 0;i<NAMES.length;i++) {
Integer search = COLUMNVALUES.contains(NAMES[i]);
if (search) {
System.out.println("Result Found: " NAMES[i]);
}
}`

Comment: In terms of collections a `Excel` sheet is a `Map` of rows having the row number as the `key` and a `Map` of cells as the `value`. The Maps of cells have the column number or the column letter as the `key` and the cell value as the `value`. If we take the Excel sheet as a database, then it is a `List` of rows except row 1 where each row is a `Map` having the column name (cell value in first row) as `key` and the cell value of that cell in this column as `value`. But why almost all must be a collection? Take the sheet as a `List` of POJOs having the properties `Name`, `ID`, `Location`, `Date`.